# Print Unicode emoji from API response

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, emoji

I am receiving the string `@"\\U0001F603"` from an API, which is the Unicode code point for the emoji .

I want to display it using an `UILabel`'s `text` property. If I directly set it, it shows `\U0001F603` instead of the actual emoji.

How can I display the emoji at the received Unicode code point?

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove first slash.
like this

label.text=@"\U0001F603";

.

Comment: The value is not hardcoded (and compiled) in the project, it's coming from a server in a variable.

Answer (score -1):

This usually helps me

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:model.UTF8String];
```